# Entering a New line in column data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am required to enter data in the column Text(nvarchar(max)) of a table 'Message' such that it will have the new line carriages in it. Selecting the column of the table would display the data in new lines. 
I have tried inserting the string with CHAR(13), but it does not work.
Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What are you looking at the data with?

Comment: I am selecting the column of the table. I am also using the column as the body of an email. The new line does not appear.

Comment: Can you show your code/select query?  There's no way we can guess at what you're trying to do.

Comment: Agree with roryap. Some code would help. Char(10) or char(13) should work. You can verify it by select the column from db, then copy and paste it in notepad. Perhaps the disconnect is in the code and/or how it's being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operating system will determine the interpretation of a line break: [LineBreak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

- \r\n for the DOS\Windows world
- \r for the pre-OSX Mac world
- \n for the Unix and Unix-like systems (OSX)

In SQL:

- CHAR(13) -- Carriage Return => \r
- CHAR(10) -- Line Feed => \n

All OS will treat \r\n as a newline so using `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` (in this order) will give you your desired results.  If your output is sent to HTML, then you'll need to use `<pre>` tags to keep the format, or you can change to using `<br/>` tags.

Comment: The pre tag was deprecated in html 4.0 and will not work at all in html 5. Don't use that.

Comment: I used CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(10) together and I got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` instead of just `CHAR(13)`. If that won't work, try just `CHAR(10)`.
You can also use `NCHAR()` for the Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `sp_send_dbmail` procedure from the msdb, you can utilize `<BR>`.

**Ex:**

```
Set @Body = @Body + '<BR><BR><BR>***********************************************************************<BR>'
Set @Body = @Body + 'This is an automated notification.'
```

**Equals:**
BODY
***********************************************************************
This is an automated notification.